# Entity Framework - Code First - Relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am new to using EF6 with code-first, and I don't now how to create a correct relationship in my map.

Basically I have this entity

```
Menu
MenuGrupo

Menu 1 x N MenuGrupo
```

Somenthing, like `Menu 1 X n MenuItens`

These are my classes:

```
public class Menu
{
        public Menu()
        {
            ListaFilhos = new List<Menu>();
        }

        public Int32 MenuID { get; set; }
        public String Nome { get; set; }
        public String Action { get; set; }
        public String Controller { get; set; }
        public String Url { get; set; }
        public Int32? Pai { get; set; }
        public Boolean? Ativo { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Menu> ListaFilhos { get; set; }
}

public class MenuMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Entidade.Menu>
{
        public MenuMap()
        {
            HasKey(x => x.MenuID);
            Property(x => x.MenuID).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
            Property(x => x.Pai).IsRequired();
            Property(x => x.Nome).HasColumnType("varchar").HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();
            Property(x => x.Url).HasColumnType("varchar").HasMaxLength(250);
            Property(x => x.Action).HasColumnType("varchar").HasMaxLength(50);
            Property(x => x.Controller).HasColumnType("varchar").HasMaxLength(50);
            Property(x => x.Ativo).IsRequired();
            ToTable("Menu");
        }
}

public class MenuGrupo
{
        public MenuGrupo()
        {
            ListaMenu = new List<Menu>();
        }

        public Int32 MenuGrupoID { get; set; }
        public Int32 MenuID { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Menu> ListaMenu { get; set; }
}

public class MenuGrupoMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Entidade.MenuGrupo>
{
        public MenuGrupoMap()
        {
            HasKey(x => x.MenuGrupoID);
            Property(x => x.MenuGrupoID).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
            Property(x => x.MenuID).IsRequired();
            ToTable("MenuGrupo");            
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at [Getting Started with Entity Framework 6 Code First using MVC 5](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application). It is really very helpful and let you build your project properly.

Regarding to your situation, it would be enough to use DataAnnotations instead of Fluent API at least for starting.

Hoıpe this helps...

Answer (score 0):

You're using `List<Menu>`, whereas you should be using `ICollection<Menu>`. The reason why this is necessary is pretty low-level, but suffice to say, it has to do with how Entity Framework handles relationships and things like lazy-loading. A `List<T>` property requires that the query be executed immediately.